# Passing Python variables via command line?

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-arguments

I'm new to Python (as in, yesterday), so bear with me if I don't know 'the obvious' yet.

There are two ways I could go about this, and either would work fine for me, and I'm not sure if `getopt` or `optparse` contains what I want/need (from what I'm reading)? I would like to do something similar to the following:

```
python this.py --variable VariableName="Value" -v VariableName2="Value2"
```

OR

```
python this.py --VariableName "Value"
```

The main issue I'm facing is that I may need to optionally pass any of the variables in, but not necessarily all and in any particular order (ergo, a raw `sys.argv` won't work in my case). For some of these variables, I may be passing strings, numbers and/or arrays.

Once the variables are passed in the script, one way or another I'll need to check if they are set / not null and assign default values as necessary.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to do a first and answer my own question.

As much as I like the answer @mgilson gave, I found an 'easier' way. I'm very comfortable with regular expressions, and figuring out an associative array (i.e., Dictionary) isn't too difficult.

```
import re

args = {}
args['pythonFile'] =  sys.argv[0]

for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
  variable = re.search('\-\-(.*)\=',arg)
  variable = variable.group(1)
  value = re.search('\=(.*)',arg)
  value = value.group(1)
  args[variable] = value

print args
```

Here's the proof:

```
$ /opt/python27/bin/python2.7 Test.py --var1=1 --var2="Testing This"
{'var1': '1', 'pythonFile': 'Test.py', 'var2': 'Testing This'}
```

Woot!

Comment: Although this sounds very clever (indeed), perhaps it's not the most "pythonic" way to achieve what you really want, from what I've seen around. But don't worry, you'll soon absorb python's characteristics and use them naturally the more you use them.

Comment: Ha, thanks, and I was fairly certain that was the case when I wrote it. Eventually though, as I learn more I'll improve, but right now for any beginner at my level might benefit from this.

Comment: The right balance between learn-first-then-do or do-whatever-works-right-now depends on the balance between the need to solve the problem vs. the need to learn the tool. But I guess this applies for every problem-tool relationship... (depth-first-searching can be paralyzing...)

Answer (score 7):

You definitely want a commandline argument parser.  Python ships with a few.  Python2.7 has [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) which can be back-ported to earlier versions as necessary and is what I would recommend.  There's also [`optparse`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/optparse.html).  It's not quite as nice as `argparse`, but it can still do a good bit and is available with older python versions as well as newer ones.

There's also [`getopt`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/getopt.html), but that one is hardly worth mentioning in comparison to the others.

Answer (score 1):

I refactored the above code a little to be more flexible and modular (great solution by the way). You can now add something like `--dev` instead of `--dev=true`. Or you can do both. It also wont crash the app if you don't add any args.

```
def get_cli_args():
    """
    Returns a dictionary of arguments passed to through the CLI.
    """

    import re
    import sys

    args = {}

    for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
        var = re.search('\-\-([A-Za-z]*)', arg) # optional value assignment
        var = var.group(1)
        value = re.search('\=(.*)', arg)
        value = value.group(1) if value else None
        args[var] = value

    return args
```